# How to deal with tuples when returned from an aync function within highland streams?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, highland.js

I use `tsc@2.3.4` and `highland@^2.13.0`.

I have an async function that returns a tuple of the type `[string, string[]]`.

I have worked with highland in the past, and I know that I can work with promises by creating a new highland stream with the promise, and resolving the promise through flattening it.

So what I am doing is basically: creating promises, parallelizing their consumption, and in the end I want one stream of `[string, string[]]` via `flatten`.

Yet highland actual behavior contradicts my expectation.

Here my TypeScript code showcasing my expectation:

```
import * as highland from "highland";

const somethingAsync = async (s: string): Promise<[string, string[]]> => {
    return [s, s.split("")];
};

const data = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
    "poit",
    "gnarf",
];

const stream: Highland.Stream<[string, string[]]> = highland(data)
    .map((input: string) => highland(somethingAsync(input))) // wrapping the promises into a highland stream
    .parallel(3) // processing it in parallel
    .flatten(); // flattening it to resolve the promises

stream.each((shouldBeATuple: [string, string[]]) => {
    console.log(shouldBeATuple);

    const [item1, item2] = shouldBeATuple;
    console.log(item1, item2);
});
```

I expect shouldBeATuple to actually be a tuple. Yet instead I get a stream of all the elements, as if `flatten` flattens too much.

I expect it to be on first iteration:

```
 ["foo", ["f","o","o"]];
```

and on second one:

```
 ["bar", ["b","a","r"]];
```

Yet what I get instead is:

```
 "foo",
```

and then it will be followed by: "f", "o", "o", "bar", "b", "a", "r".

So I lose the tuples completely and get one big "mess" of a stream with all the elements in it.

How can I get a stream of tuples when using async functions?

---

I found out that when I do not flatten the stream I get my result yet typescript will throw an error:

```
15 const stream: Highland.Stream<[string, string[]]> = highland(data)
         ~~~~~~
src/tuple.ts(15,7): error TS2322: Type 'Stream<Stream<[string, string[]]>>' is not assignable to type 'Stream<[string, string[]]>'.
  Type 'Stream<[string, string[]]>' is not assignable to type '[string, string[]]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type 'Stream<[string, string[]]>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The type declaration for `parallel` is wrong.  When it is corrected, your code passes the type checker without the `flatten`.  I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29003) to fix the typings; you can add a copy of the corrected typings from there to your project.